# GDB doesn't find debugging symbols in Rust executable

Tags: gdb, rust, symbols, missing-symbols

This is my Cargo.toml with debugging settings:

```
[package] 
name = "rpolysolve" 
version = "0.1.0" 
authors = ["stiv"]

[dependencies] 
[profile.dev] 
debug = true  
opt-level = 0
```

As I can see from console output, cargo has not removed debug symbols:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.66 secs
```

I have downloaded gdb-7.9.1-tdm64-2 to my C:\gdb-7.9.1-tdm64-2 folder on windows7. Now I try to launch it with this command from project folder:

```
C:\gdb-7.9.1-tdm64-2\gdb64\bin\gdb.exe ./target/debug/rpolysolve.exe

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
... GNU blablabla cut here ...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./target/debug/rpolysolve.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

As you see it says **no debugging symbols found** and there is now way how I can set a breakpoint. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Rust are you using? `-msvc` or `-gnu`?

Comment: C:\Users\steve\.cargo\bin>rustc.exe -V
rustc 1.18.0 (03fc9d622 2017-06-06)

Comment: Try `rustc.exe -vV`

Comment: Yes, the toolchain was wrong, msvc binaries doesn't seem to work with gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the solution is to switch toolchain, i.e. to make binaries be compatible with GNU:

```
rustup install stable-gnu 
rustup default stable-gnu
```

I don't know if there is gdb.exe for msvc toolchain.

Comment: The gnu toolchain doesn't understand how to consume native Windows executables or debug symbols. If you're trying to debug Rust code produced by the `-msvc` toolchain, you can use any Windows native debugger like `windgb`, Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code with the C++ debugger.